# Measuring distance between related points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, point, distance, proximity

How can I generate a table with measured distances between two related point layers?

Every point from A layer has at least 1 assigned point in B layer and the attribute that defines relation between them is saved in separate table (A layer->table-> B layer). I have made relations in arcGIS to define pairs of points. Now I need to know what is the distance between them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [Generate Near Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm) tool if you have ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced license. Another way is writing a script using arcpy library. See [distanceTo](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm) method (the distance between the two geometries).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Points To Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/points-to-line.htm) and then calculate the geometry (length) of the resulting lines.

You say you have a relationship established already so this tool can use that key field to connect the dots between related points and ignore other non-related points that might be close by.